# IPAD devices do not have USB access in WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, permissions, windows-server-2008, ipad

Our systems are connected to a Domain machine ( running Windows 2008 ). There are certain policies enabled such as USB permission, Admin privilege, registry access etc. Users in these group only have the corresponding permission. My problem is when I add a user to  USB allow group he  will  get USB  permission for all USB devices including pen drive, android device , but not IPAD , IPOD etc. Do you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to log in to the computer as an Admin and go into the control panel / system / device manager.

Whilst watching the screen plug in the iPod/iPad/iPhone and you'll see portable devices - indent this to show the driver, right click and uninstall driver.

OK, unplug the iPod/iPad/iPhone and plug it back into another USB socket and watch the computer find the device and install the driver.

From here your problem should be fixed, log back in as a normal user with permissions now restored.